# Default export eslint

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I trying to create a structure for my react-redux app and I have a problem with eslint default export rule (I am using Airbnb guide).

Basicly my structure looks like this:

```
src/
|-----modules/
|--------Component1/
|------------component.js
|------------index.js
|--------index.js
|-----App.js
```

.

```
// component.js
import React from 'react';

const Component1 = () => (
   <div>Hello</div>
);

export default Component1;
```

.

```
//Component1/index.js

export { default as Component1 } from './component';
// This is where I get eslint error
```

.

```
//modules/index.js

export * from './Component1';
// This is where I get eslint error
```

.

```
//App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Component1 } from './modules';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Component1 />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app');
```

Because I am using Redux there can be reducers to export from component too, so then I would use simple export with two parameters.

Should I take a different approuche or ignore eslint rule?

Edit: I was prefering to import/prefer-default-export rule. I know that I can disable it but should I?

Comment: what does the eslint error say?

Comment: You can read about the advantages named export instead default export of https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2019/01/stop-using-default-exports-javascript-module/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are talking about `prefer-default-export` rule. It is very common to use named exports, you should configure linter to match your and your team preferences (as well as airbnb does). I would personally ignore this rule but it is up to you.

In addition you can create local `.eslintrc` file in `src/modules` where you can ignore the rule and it will be also ignored in subdirectories relative to this file.